# Is it impossible to verify that a website is using their publicly released source code in production?

Tags: web-services, open-source, trust

This is a bit of an oddball question, and I've seen nothing similar asked anywhere on the internet.

### What I want to do

I want to release the source code of my website. Beyond that, the nature of the website (described below) is such that I not only want to release the source code, but I want users of my website to be able to unequivocally verify that they're using the *exact* version of the website as is in the source code dump.

The part that makes it tough is that **my good will cannot be trusted**. (Obviously, it can since I'm going to this length, but from the user's perspective it cannot).

### My (mental exercises) to try to fix this

#### Attempt 1

So, the first thing I thought about was hashing the source code, or even hashing the entire docker container it's running in, and providing an endpoint that broadcasts that hash, so that it may be matched up against the public source code.

#### Attempt 2

The second thing I thought about was providing users with a read-only shell login so that they would be able to hash the docker image that's being run. The problem here is, there's no way to verify that the docker image is what is running (to my knowlege). I could just build an image of the public source code and put it there for users to hash.

Also, because of the security concern, I really hate the idea of putting users that close to production.

#### Attempt 3

Finally, I wondered if it would solve the problem if I used some type of blockchain technology, like a distributed app. But that's so complex, and I don't think it provides extra trust.

### Why I want to do this

I am building a website that will be handling incredibly personal data. It could destroy people's lives if any of it was leaked (and no, the TLD isn't `.xxx` or anything like that. In fact, nothing illegal is going on with this data). However, there is an intense social stigma associated with the type of data, and it actually is enough evidence (in some countries) to peruse the death penalty against a user, if any data is leaked.

So, in addition to having a very explicit (and secure) Privacy Policy, I want to make an open source promise to my users, so that problems can be hunted down by volunteers and quickly eliminated. Also so that they're able to verify that I'm not adding code into the running production version to enable extra spying on them.

Is this type of thing theoretically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the server receives some of this incredibly personal user data in a format that it/you can read it, there is no perfect way.  You would have to let the users encrypt the data before uploading it, with a key only they know.
If there is no data transfer involved, then the users can check the code in the browser and compare hashes manually. Perhaps there is an automatic way of doing this. Anyway all work on the data then has to be performed on the client side.

The core problem is that a user has to trust the complete environment, from source code over compiler to executing OS and hardware.
You cannot cryptographically ensure that you do not for example intercept the running program on a low layer and read out data there, even if you had a possibility to ensure that you run the exact code on the server.

Comment: I think that unfortunately this is the right answer here. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't an obvious thing to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Trust", you can build by legalities and Privacy Policies.

We all willingly keep our sensitive data online in many applications/systems and we never check to see if the source code or the architecture of the system is the same as what they promised at the beginning.

As [@tystackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10281857/tystackoverflow) said, building a backdoor in the code is not the only way you can ensure the users of a system that their data is not accessible to anyone else. In this case your system architecture should also support encryption of data at higher level that no one (unless accessed through the system) can have direct access to it.

I do understand the risk of these data leaking,
It all depends on how you design the System to be tamper proof and secure, and conveying the idea behind the security measures you have built in to the Application to its users.

Good Luck with the Project !